# How to write a generic sample function in V?

Tags: generics, polymorphism, vlang

I would like to implement a generic `sample` function for arrays in V. The inspiration for this is [`base::sample()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) in R.

A very basic prototype without the `replace` and `prob` options of the R function and limited to integer arrays could look like this:

```
pub fn sample_int(arr[] int, size int) []int {

  mut res := [0].repeat(size)
  for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    res[i] = arr[rand.next(arr.len)]
  }

  return res

}
```

Is it possible at the moment to make this function generic to work with all kinds of arrays? How would I implement this?

There is a section about generics in the [V documentation](https://vlang.io/docs#generics), but I was not able to figure it out with this example code. I also searched for examples in the V repo, but I only found ToDo comments where generics are supposed to be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are very outdated with the progress of V. Here is the code of how to use generics in V with your function. Also join the discord server for discussions and more talks.

```golang
pub fn sample_int<T>(arr[] T, size int) []T {

  mut res := [arr[1]].repeat(size)
  for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    res[i] = arr[rand.next(arr.len)]
  }

  return res

}
```